# Navigating In IE Using Excel VBA By ID

Tags: html, excel, internet-explorer, vba

Problem: Attempting to copy/paste information from Excel into a webpage and then push button. Will eventually need to get this all the way to having it print a PDF into a folder. I attempted the code below, but am completely unsure why it is not working. Google didn't resolve.

Website: https://www.easymapmaker.com/advanced

Attempted Code:

```
    Sub MapMacro()

    AddressGrid = Range("A1").Value

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    WebSite = "https://www.easymapmaker.com/advanced"
    With IE
      .Visible = True
      .navigate WebSite

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    On Error Resume Next 'This is here in case fields cant be found.

    Set Address = IE.Document.getElementsByID("sourceData")
    Address.Value = AddressGrid


    Set Element = IE.Document.getElementsByID("optionButton")
    Element.Click

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It may be easier to see what is being sent as a package when you click on the button, e.g. a POST or a GET request. Instead of making an IE explorer instance you can just make a connection and send data without all the loading html elements and blah blah. Use F12 in IE to monitor your traffic and emulate it? It also means you don't have to do "waiting" cycles, requests get sent asynchronously and code carries on when you get a valid response.

Comment: I got the button to work. I need to use the IE object for this due to Adobe PDF requirements. Do I have the incorrect ID for where I need to copy the info?

Comment: It looks right, did you try the one above - displayTable

Comment: Just tried that still nothing. Think ID it wrong, am I using the operations correctly? I took out the s on getElement(s)

Comment: I think the issue is with the  Address.Value = AddressGrid line

Comment: I just got it working with `IE.Document.getElementById("sourceData").Value = AddressGrid` note taking out the 's' in Element(s) was correct, you just don't need to do `Set Address = ` ... skip that and do it directly as above

Answer (score 0):

TO clarify, I got this working by changing the lines:

```
Set Address = IE.Document.getElementsByID("sourceData")
Address.Value = AddressGrid
```

to:

```
IE.Document.getElementByID("sourceData").Value = AddressGrid
```

Now, since AddressGrid is only referring to one cell but you want a range, say "A1:D4" you could try this method:

```
Dim clipTXT As MSForms.DataObject
Range("A1:D4").Copy

Set clipTXT = New MSForms.DataObject
    clipTXT.GetFromClipboard
IE.Document.getElementByID("sourceData").Value = clipTXT.GetTxt
```

Comment: Try copying the range: `Range("A1:D4").Copy` and then instead of using `AddressGrid` you could now get the data straight from the clipboard into the "sourceData" element. I'll edit my answer. Please upvote if it helps!!